# Почему при выполнении условия выдает NULL?

Tags: javascript

```js
var name = prompt("Введите Ваше имя", "");
if (name == null)
  name = "НЕЗНАКОМЕЦ";
var s = "<h1>Привет, " + name + "!</h1>";
document.write(s);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конфликт с свойством `window.name`.

```js
var name1 = prompt("Введите Ваше имя", "");
if (name1 == null)
  name1 = "НЕЗНАКОМЕЦ";
var s = "<h1>Привет, " + name1 + "!</h1>";
document.write(s);
```

Comment: Ну можно же пояснение добавить

Comment: Спасибо ! А то чуть не закипел от непонимания куда шагать.

Comment: @СергейШрамко Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Answer (score 2):

Потому что условие не выполняется, т.к., если ничего не вводить, то значение name будет не null, а undefined, null != undefined, вот так правильно:

```js
var name = prompt("Введите Ваше имя", "");
if (!name)
  name = "НЕЗНАКОМЕЦ";
var s = "<h1>Привет, " + name + "!</h1>";
document.write(s);
```